# Not able to login with magento site admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I could not able to login to my magento site admin, after moved the magento site from one server to anther server.

Even i have tried the following things, but not able to login. Please help me to resolve this issue, since i am new to magento site development.

1) cleared cache files under var/cache.

2) cleared session files under var/session.

3) cleared browser cookies & cache.

4) changed base_url in core_config_data table.

5) cleared log_url table.

6) changed web/cookie/cookie_domain path in core_config_data table.

7) Change admin 'password' also. but i am not getting any invalid username/password error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this SQL request :

`SELECT *
FROM core_config_data
WHERE (path LIKE "%secure%" OR path LIKE "%cookie%") AND value LIKE "%http%"
;`

Change old website url to new one.

Clear cache, use private navigation and it should work's.